# Performance mode isn't available with a Threadripper 3970x?

Tags: 22.04, power-management

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04. Why isn't performance mode displayed? I have a Threadripper 3970x. Is this hardware not compatible?

[image: setting]

Answer (score 2):

The "Performance Mode" option is not available on all systems as it comes down to whatever `powerprofilesctl` is able to read from the UEFI on your motherboard. Many workstation and server-grade motherboards have just two settings available for the OS:

- Use what's needed when it's needed (active processing)
- Use as little as possible because the system idles most of the time (passive processing)

"Balanced" is generally sufficient for most desktop situations but, if you *really* want to change the setting, you can do so in the Terminal with this command:

```
powerprofilesctl set performance
```

**Notes:**

1. Setting the power profile to something that is not displayed in the Gnome Control Centre can result in the window failing to open.
2. There is no guarantee that `powerprofilesctl` will be able to set your machine to "Performance Mode" if the UEFI does not actually have this mode.
3. On some Zen1 and Zen2-based processors, changing the profile to an unsupported value has resulted in NUMA-related issues, where performance actually *degraded*. I do not know if this will affect your processor. However, in the event that you see degraded performance as a result of the setting change, a reboot usually clears up the mess.

Comment: Thank's for you'r reply !!!